# IntegrityError at /contacts/import

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

in django when i am going to import csv file and parse it i am getting following erro

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: inven_app_clientcontact.author_id
>   [29/Apr/2019 17:56:32] "POST /contacts/import HTTP/1.1" 500 188071

here is my code

```
   @login_required
def contact_upload(request):
    template = 'site/contact_upload.html'
    prompt = {
        'order': 'Order of the CSV should be client_name, client_company_name, email, work_phone'
    }

if request.method == 'GET':
    return render(request, template, prompt)

csv_file = request.FILES['file']

if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
    messages.error(request, 'This is not a csv file')

data_set = csv_file.read().decode('utf-8')
io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
next(io_string)

for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar='|'):
    _, created = ClientContact.objects.filter(author=request.user).update_or_create(
        client_name=column[0],
        client_company_name=column[1],
        email=column[2],
        work_phone=column[3]
    )
context = {}

return render(request, template, context)
```

any help would be appriciated. Thank you. If any code is needed please let me know

Comment: I think some row inside the csv doesn't have an id. So Django can't create the object

Comment: A sample of the content of the csv could help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests that you are trying to save an object without a user. You haven't showed the full traceback which will show exactly where the error is occurring, but it could be in your `update_or_create` call - you should set `author` in the defaults or add it to the kwargs. For example:

```
_, created = ClientContact.objects.filter().update_or_create(
    client_name=column[0],
    client_company_name=column[1],
    email=column[2],
    work_phone=column[3],
    author=request.user,
)
```

Comment: please look above now i have another problem. it shows me a slug but i have id

Comment: It's a similar problem to before - `slug` is a required field, so you have to set it. You probably want to add `slug` to `defaults` when you call [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create), otherwise you might end up with multiple rows which are unique apart from the slug.

Comment: i do not have a slug field but do i need to set?

Comment: *i do not have a slug field* - the error message mentions `inven_app_clientcontact.slug` so it looks like you *do* have a slug field.

Comment: but i cannot find where it is

Comment: Looks like it's in your `ClientContact` model.

Comment: yes but it had i have removed it before i have encountered this problem

Comment: It sounds like you forgot to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` after removing the field from your model. If you're still stuck after doing that, then I can't help you here because it's a different issue.

Comment: it finally works. I have deleted all db and again run makemigrations and migrate. After that it is working